# My bot keeps spamming the same message. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require("./ayalar.json");
let takipedilen = "648424230081265664";
let onlinetakipedilen = 648424230081265664;
let hesap = "648424230081265664";

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!oldMember.id == onlinetakipedilen) return;
    if (oldMember.id == onlinetakipedilen) {
        if (oldMember.presence.status != newMember.presence.status) {
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                // use the message's channel (TextChannel) to send a new message
                client.guilds
                    .get("812505935280472084")
                    .channels.get("812506306321580062")
                    .send("**" + `${newMember.user.username}` + "**" + " " + "şuanda" + " " + `${newMember.presence.status}`)
                    .catch(console.error); // add error handling here
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

This my code and it's spamming the same thing to my text channel.
This is the result;
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the first evaluation kind of wrong.

Instead of doing this:

```js
if(!oldMember.id == onlinetakipedilen) return;
```

try:

```js
if(oldMember.id !== onlinetakipedilen) return;
```

Comment: I tried this parameter but its still spamming.

Comment: by the way, where's `onlinetakipedilen` set?

Comment: At top, there is the code;





const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require('./ayalar.json');
let takipedilen = "648424230081265664";
let onlinetakipedilen = 648424230081265664;
let hesap = "648424230081265664";
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `onlinetakipedilen` is an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Replace 5th line with:

```js
let onlinetakipedilen = "648424230081265664";
```

---

If you are wondering why this is happening please read [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179).

---

You're also comparing a `Boolean` to an `Integer`.

```js
if (oldMember.id !== onlinetakipedilen)
```

[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)